# Regex function to extract the email body using python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dataframe containing number of emails. I need to remove the header and the footer and **keep only the body of the email**, can it be done.

I would prefer a regex function.

I have tried the regex function given below to remove **Best regards** but this does not work. At times instead it is **Sincerely**.

```
re.sub(r'\b(Best regards,)\b*?$','',df2[1][0])
```

I'm new to regrex can someone help. I also need to remove 
    **Abc,
    Dear Name**,

```
Abc
Dear Name,


I am writing this to request you for an extension on the XYZ project report which is due on {date}. 
My mother has taken ill unexpectedly, and I must leave for home tonight. I’m afraid it will take me a 
week before I can return to the office and complete the report.
Kindly grant me an extension till {date} for the same. I promise to deliver the project report by 
then.

Best regards,
Coordinator.
Customer Care**
```

Comment: Regex only works with regular grammar. If all your emails follow the same pattern, you're good to go (but we'd need to know the pattern), if not, regex is not the right solution

Comment: Do you know the body of the email is always two newlines from the body, and there will *always* be Best Regards or Sincerely afterwords (and never in the body)? If so I can build you a regex

Comment: @maor10 Yes, can you help me with the regex function

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you could probably use a custom function to apply it to that column of your dataframe. Something like this:

```py
def extractBody(emailString):
    salutes = ["dear"] # A list containing greetings key words, like 'dear', 'hi', etc
    goodbyes = ["best regards"] # A list containing email footers like 'best regards' 'bye', etc

    # Split your email by line breaks and make everything lowercase
    emailLines = emailString.lower().split("\n")
    normalLines = emailString.split("\n")

    # Start and end points to extract the text
    start = -1
    end = len(emailLines) - 1

    for i in range(len(emailLines)):
        line  = emailLines[i]

        # Check if any salute words in this line
        if len([s for s in salutes if s in line]) and start == -1:
            start = i + 1
            continue

        # Check if any goodbyes in this line
        if len([s for s in goodbyes if s in line]) and end == len(emailLines) - 1:
            end = i
            break

    if start == -1:
        return "\n".join(normalLines[:end])
    else:
        return "\n".join(normalLines[start:end])
```

When I execute this function on your provided input (stored in the **mail** variable), these are the results:

```py
extract =  extractBody(mail).strip()
print(f"{extract}")
>>>
I am writing this to request you for an extension on the XYZ project report which is due on {date}.
My mother has taken ill unexpectedly, and I must leave for home tonight. I’m afraid it will take me a week before I can return to the office and complete the report.
Kindly grant me an extension till {date} for the same. I promise to deliver the project report by
then.
```

Now you should apply this function to your desired text in the dataframe. Please let me know if this helps! :D